# SQL Delete Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to write an SQL script that selects one record in table1, then does a lookup in the remaining tables in the database.  If it doesn't find the record, I need delete the record from table1.  Anyone provide some sample script?

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete explanation of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Why would you do such a thing one record at a time?

Comment: Is the end goal to delete all records in table1 that don't have a corresponding record?

Comment: How many tables are you looking up the record in?

Comment: @VeeArr: We have a database that has purged records from all tables based on a date timestamp, but there is one table that has no date timestamp. I need to delete records from here that do not exist anywhere else. @HLGEM: I don't need to do one record at a time, but i just wanted to get a base script down. I've done selects and deletes where records exist, but not the opposite. There are approximatley 10 tables that I'm looking up. @Martin Smith: Yes. – jerle78 7 secs ago edit

Answer (score 3):

One example

```
delete table1
where not exists (select 1 
                   from Table2 
                   where table1.SomeColumn = Table2.SomeColumn)
AND table1.SomeColumn = 5 --just an example,
```

Leave the AND out if you want to delete all the rows from table 1 that do not exist in table 2

you can also use LEFT JOIN or NOT IN

Answer (score 2):

I have done things like this:

```
DELETE table1
  FROM table1
 WHERE table1.ID NOT IN (
       SELECT RefID FROM Table2
       UNION
       SELECT RefID FROM Table3
       ...
       )
```

Assuming RefID are FK's to table1.ID. Is this what you need?

Comment: This would work well if checking against multiple tables. I'd make it a "UNION ALL", of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE id=10 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE id=10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Very generally, (since you gave little details)

```
Delete Table1 t1
Where [Criteria to find table1 Record]
  And Not Exists(Select * From Table2
                 Where pk = t1.Pk)
  And Not Exists(Select * From Table3
                 Where pk = t1.Pk)
  And Not Exists(Select * From Table4
                 Where pk = t1.Pk)
  ... etc. for all other tables
```

Comment: @VeeArr:  We have a database that has purged records from all tables based on a date timestamp, but there is one table that has no date timestamp.  I need to delete records from here that do not exist anywhere else.

@HLGEM: I don't need to do one record at a time, but i just wanted to get a base script down. I've done selects and deletes where records exist, but not the opposite. There are approximatley 10 tables that I'm looking up.

@Martin Smith:  Yes.